# Substitute string within lstinputlisting command

Tags: listings, xstring, underscore

`listings`'s package command `\lstinputlisting` should have the following syntax for filenames with underscores:
`\lstinputlisting[caption={a\_b.mat}]{a_b.mat}`.

I would like to automate the process of name conversion, but I am stuck on the stage of special character `_` replacement.

The command:
`\noexpandarg\StrSubstitute{a_b.mat}{_}{\_}`
works within text body, but stops working inside `\lstinputlisting`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % only need to provide the file a_b.mat
\begin{filecontents*}{a_b.mat}
    a = 1;
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mycmda}[1]{\lstinputlisting[caption={a\_b.mat}]{#1}} % WORKS
\newcommand{\mycmdb}[1]{\lstinputlisting[caption={\noexpandarg\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\_}}]{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \noexpandarg\StrSubstitute{a_b.mat}{_}{\_} % WORKS - PROOF OF CONCEPT
    \mycmda{a_b.mat}                           % WORKS
    %\mycmdb{a_b.mat}                            % DOES NOT WORK
\end{document}
```

> Paragraph ended before \lst@temp was complete. \mycmdb{a_b.mat}

How can this be overcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the changed string before passing it to `caption=`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{a_b.mat}
    a = 1;
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\matlablisting}[1]{%
  \begingroup\noexpandarg
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\_}[\mllcap]%
  \lstinputlisting[caption=\mllcap]{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\matlablisting{a_b.mat}

\end{document}
```